# Alter value of useMemo state outside of initial function block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I am rendering a list of dragon ball z characters, and within a `useMemo` the user can filter the characters based on gender, race or both.

```
  let dbzCharacters = useMemo<CharacterObj[]>(() => {
    if (filterGenderValue && filterRaceValue) {
      return characters.filter(
        (char: CharacterObj) =>
          char.race === filterRaceValue && char.gender === filterGenderValue
      );
    } else if (filterGenderValue && !filterRaceValue) {
      return characters.filter(
        (char: CharacterObj) => char.gender === filterGenderValue
      );
    } else if (!filterGenderValue && filterRaceValue) {
      return characters.filter(
        (char: CharacterObj) => char.race === filterRaceValue
      );
    } else {
      return characters;
    }
  }, [filterGenderValue, filterRaceValue]);
```

my goal now to apply the following functionality:

Whatever the state of`dbzCharacters` is, I also want to be able to search by name via an input. I do not want to code that logic into the `useMemo` block as it's going to result in a million if statements. My current attempt is to re-assign the value of `dbzCharacters` inside a `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (dbzCharacters && search.length > 1) {
      dbzCharacters = dbzCharacters.filter(({ name }: CharacterObj) =>
        name!.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }, [search, dbzCharacters]);
```

The search functionality is not working as is. the `dbzCharacters` is not altering. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: You can filter in an other new memo named as example: dbzCharactersFilteredByName. And render this data instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that your current `useMemo` is getting quite complex and adding a name search would make it only more complex. However the complexity is due to the fact that you want to catch all the scenarios with a single `filter()` call.

Instead you can use if-statements (not *else if*) to incrementally apply the filters.

```
let cbzCharacters = useMemo<CharacterObj[]>(() => {
  let cbzCharacters = characters; // characters should also be in the dependency array if it's not static

  if (filterGenderValue) {
    cbzCharacters = cbzCharacters.filter(
      (char: CharacterObj) => char.gender === filterGenderValue
    );
  }

  if (filterRaceValue) {
    cbzCharacters = cbzCharacters.filter(
      (char: CharacterObj) => char.race === filterRaceValue
    );
  }

  if (search.length > 1) {
    cbzCharacters = cbzCharacters.filter(
      ({ name }: CharacterObj) => name!.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  return cbzCharacters;
}, [filterGenderValue, filterRaceValue, search]);
```

---

Alternatively you could also use multiple `useMemo` calls, which achieves the same thing.

```
let cbzCharacters = characters;

cbzCharacters = useMemo<CharacterObj[]>(() => {
  if (!filterGenderValue) return cbzCharacters;

  return cbzCharacters.filter(
    (char: CharacterObj) => char.gender === filterGenderValue
  );
}, [cbzCharacters, filterGenderValue]);

cbzCharacters = useMemo<CharacterObj[]>(() => {
  if (!filterRaceValue) return cbzCharacters;

  return cbzCharacters.filter(
    (char: CharacterObj) => char.race === filterRaceValue
  );
}, [cbzCharacters, filterRaceValue]);

cbzCharacters = useMemo<CharacterObj[]>(() => {
  if (search.length <= 1) return cbzCharacters;

  return cbzCharacters.filter(
    ({ name }: CharacterObj) => name!.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );
}, [cbzCharacters, search]);
```

---

There is also the option to write a custom hook to extract some of the complexity. I'm not that familiar with TypeScript so the code below is written in normal JavaScript. It is intended to provide you with inspiration rather than a direct solution.

```js
// Applies filters upon a given array. The amount of filters must be static.
// Each filter must provide 3 properties.
//
//   * applyIf - A function that signifies if the filter should be applied.
//   * filter - The filter function passed to `array.filter()`.
//   * deps - Must list all dependencies used in `applyIf` and `filter`. The length
//            must be static. If there are no dependencies pass an empty array.
//
function useFilters(array, filters) {
  return useMemo(() => {
    return filters
      .filter(({applyIf}) => applyIf())
      .reduce((array, {filter}) => array.filter(filter), array);
  }, [array, ...filters.flatMap(({deps}) => deps)]);
}
```

```js
let cbzCharacters = useFilters(characters, [{
  applyIf: () => filterGenderValue,
  filter: (char) => char.gender === filterGenderValue,
  deps: [filterGenderValue],
}, {
  applyIf: () => filterRaceValue,
  filter: (char) => char.race === filterRaceValue,
  deps: [filterRaceValue],
}, {
  applyIf: () => search.length > 1,
  filter: (char) => char.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()),
  deps: [search],
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the useEffect code inside the useMemo without extra code.

```js
 let dbzCharacters = useMemo<CharacterObj[]>(() => {
    let result = null;
    if (filterGenderValue && filterRaceValue) {
      result = characters.filter(
        (char: CharacterObj) =>
          char.race === filterRaceValue && char.gender === filterGenderValue
      );
    } else if (filterGenderValue && !filterRaceValue) {
      result = characters.filter(
        (char: CharacterObj) => char.gender === filterGenderValue
      );
    } else if (!filterGenderValue && filterRaceValue) {
      result = characters.filter(
        (char: CharacterObj) => char.race === filterRaceValue
      );
    } else {
      result = characters;
    }
    if (result && search.length > 1) {
      return result.filter(({ name }: CharacterObj) =>
        name!.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
    return result;
  }, [filterGenderValue, filterRaceValue, search]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to apply the same logic but inside another `useMemo` and render that.

```
  const dbzCharsFilterByName = useMemo<CharacterObj[]>(() => {
    return search.length > 0 && dbzCharacters
      ? dbzCharacters.filter(({ name }: CharacterObj) =>
          name!.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
      : dbzCharacters;
  }, [search, dbzCharacters]);
```